After updgrading to Ubuntu 24.10 from 24.04, start getting error message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
When I upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10 I start getting message "recipient disconnected from message bus without replying" while trying to open any folder/file. I'm running on util-linux=2.40.2-1ubuntu1
